# adding config file to classpath-java

Tags: java, classpath, typesafe-config

I have below deployment structure.

[image]

Inside my config folder , I have a config file `jms.conf`.
Now when I am trying to run the application using below command it is running into an error.

```
java -Dconfig=syn-tac -Dupstream.xyz.login.DATASTREAM_REF="20190102" -Djms.config=solace **-classpath "./config/jms.conf:./tradeprocessor-1.2.8-SNAPSHOT.jar"** com.abc.main.MainComponent
```

Application starts running, so it picks up the jar, but runs into this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$IO: jms.conf: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: jms.conf
```

How I am picking up the configuration is using typeSafe API in java using the below lines of code:

```
import com.typesafe.config.Config;

import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;

...

Config configLoad3 = ConfigFactory.parseResourcesAnySyntax("jms.conf", cpConfig);
```

Just want to check how I can include this configuration file in classpath and read it from the application.Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try just putting `./config` in the classpath. If that doesn't do it, try putting a slash before `jms.conf` in the `ConfigFactory` call.

Comment: @BretC  spot on.I added ./config to classpath and it worked. Thanks :)

Buy why providing complete path doesnt include the file?

Comment: I think classpath entries only work for archives and directories, not individual files